# SESSION variable slow to update textfield in php

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a form, contained 3 fields, which when the submit button in submitted,
it will changes the session variable values according to the fields, in this case there are 3 variables. then i echo back the variable onto the fields.

For the first time submit, it stores the value beautifully and display in the fields correctly, the problem is that, when i submit the second time, the values are still the same. after i refresh the page, then the values in the fields are changed.

this is partially the codes i'm using now.

```
<?php
session_start();?>
?>

<form name="form1" id="form1" action="">
<input type="text" name="acc1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['acc_main']" />
<input type="text" name="acc2" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['acc_id']" />
<input type="text" name="acc3" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['acc_cat']" />
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) != '')
{
$_SESSION['acc_main'] = $_POST['acc1'];
$_SESSION['acc_id'] = $_POST['acc2'];
$_SESSION['acc_cat'] = $_POST['acc3'];
}
?>
```

After i refresh(F5), then the value changed. i want it to be, when i clicked the submit button, it will change to the new value.

Comment: Put your `isset($_POST['submit'])` section before the form, after `session_start()`, you are not closing your PHP tag `value="<?php echo $_SESSION['acc_main']; ?>"`

Comment: @CapitanFindus, i've tried like you suggested, but still the same. and also, i had put close PHP tag on the value.

Comment: You have to explicitely generate the html (using javascript DOM) after the php function call. That is after the php function call, you have to call a javascript function from there to see the updated values.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP Code:**

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']) != '')
 {
   $_SESSION['acc_main'] = $_POST['acc1'];
   $_SESSION['acc_id'] = $_POST['acc2'];
   $_SESSION['acc_cat'] = $_POST['acc3'];

   echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
        , 'jsfunctionToPrintUpdatedValues();'
        , '</script>'
     ;
 }
?>
```

**Javascript Sample Code**

```
function jsfunctionToPrintUpdatedValues()
{
     /* retrieve the updated session variables in javascript variables */

     var acc_main_js = <?php echo $_SESSION['acc_main']?>
     var acc_id_js = <?php echo $_SESSION['acc_id']?>
     var acc_cat_js = <?php echo $_SESSION['acc_cat']?>

     document.getElementById("main").value=acc_main_js;
     document.getElementById("id").value=acc_main_js;
     document.getElementById("cat").value=acc_main_js;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the input fields you have to write like this
`

> Below

`

```
<input type="text" name="acc1" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['acc_main'])) echo $_SESSION['acc_main']" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Use if(isset($_POST['submit']) != '') before the form. Change your code to this:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) != '')
    {
    $_SESSION['acc_main'] = $_POST['acc1'];
    $_SESSION['acc_id'] = $_POST['acc2'];
    $_SESSION['acc_cat'] = $_POST['acc3'];
    ?>

    <form name="form1" id="form1" action="">
    <input type="text" name="acc1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['acc_main']" />
    <input type="text" name="acc2" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['acc_id']" />
    <input type="text" name="acc3" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['acc_cat']" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>

    <?php
    }else{
    ?>

    <form name="form1" id="form1" action="">
    <input type="text" name="acc1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['acc_main']" />
    <input type="text" name="acc2" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['acc_id']" />
    <input type="text" name="acc3" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['acc_cat']" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit">

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the code. but if the the form is simple and small like the example i've given, i will use it.